# Ideas for translation of 演奏技術向上への一可能性

Tags: meaning

> 演奏技術向上への一可能性

Contextually, this is from a paper talking about teaching piano and this is the subtitle of the paper (so it is a stand alone sentence). I'm having problems translating the above sentence without it being overly awkward. The best I've come up with is:

> One possibility to improve performance skills

I believe that 技術 usually means 'technology', but in this case as piano performance is the subject, I thought skills was more apt. 'One possibility' also seems awkward to me, but I'm just not coming up with another word to replace it. I'd welcome any suggestions, thank you.

Comment: It seems like the sentence says "[something] is one possible way to[lit. towards] improve musical performance skills"

Comment: 「演奏技術向上への一可能性」は、"a sentence" (文)ではなくて、"a noun phrase" (名詞句) ではないでしょうか。。。？

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me "A potential for better technique".

技術 also means technique or skill. If "Technology" is used to mean such as engineering technologies, literally "テクノロジー" would be used. For example http://techon.nikkeibp.co.jp/ a site about technology is title as 日経テクノロジー.

可能性 can be possibility, probability, potential, etc. I suppose the paper is talking about a potential that something can have the potential of improving the techniques.